# XML body in php mail

Tags: php, xml, email

I am using php mail function.

I would like to send xml content as email body as shown below

```
$message = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
              <name part="full">Wheels.ca</name>
              <service>Wheels.ca</service>
              <url>http://www.wheels.ca/</url>';
```

I am using mail function and passing above string as message body.

In source I am getting data as XMl but in body it show it like normal text as shown below.

```
Wheels.ca
Wheels.ca
http://www.wheels.ca
```

I want xml in both body as well as in mail source.

Comment: I dont think thats possible, since e-mails are either plain text or HTML. Why dont just send it in HTML?

Comment: Yes you are right. Got it.

Comment: No problem, glad I could help.

Answer (score 0):

You have to convert the special HTML tags to entities.

```
$message = htmlspecialchars('<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
              <name part="full">Wheels.ca</name>
              <service>Wheels.ca</service>
              <url>http://www.wheels.ca/</url>');
```